# Sort downloads by most recently purchased first in my account WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Currently my-downloads.php shows the customer the oldest files first. It would be really nice to sort it by their most recent downloads at as on large file download sites, its a lot of scrolling and annoys some of our customers.

Thank you for guiding me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the `woocommerce_customer_get_downloadable_products` filter and return the array of downloads in reversed order.

```
function reverse_my_downloads_order( $downloads ) {
    return array_reverse( $downloads );
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_customer_get_downloadable_products', 'reverse_my_downloads_order' );
```

Add this code to your functions.php file of your active child-theme or theme. I didn't test it, but it should work.